# Mutliple text responses for multiple logic checks? excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logical-operators

Didn't find exactly what I'm looking for in other threads.

I have a sheet that tracks user terminations dates and identifies tasks to complete once a date is reached, like start forwarding emails to manager or suspend account after 3 months.

Current setup is as follows (relevant to question):

Value columns

- Col C = Term date
- Col T = Forwarding Requested = True or False

Formula Columns

- Col G `=IF(T4=FALSE,"N/A",(C4+IF(T4,90)))` << checks if forwarding is requested. If it is, **returns term date + 3 months**. If else, returns N/A.
- Col H `=IF(G4="N/A","N/A",IF(G4<TODAY(),"DISABLE FORWARD","HOLD TICKET"))` << checks if forwarding wait period has passed or wasn't requested. If Forwarding is requested, wait 3 months with "HOLD TICKET" text and after 3 months, return "DISABLE FORWARDING". If nothing is requested, it returns NA.

  - Col I `=IF(G4<TODAY(),"SUSPEND","HOLD TICKET")` << Checks if the forwarding wait period has passed. If it is, returns text "SUSPEND". If else, returns "HOLD TICKET".

Now, onto what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'd like Column I to also return SUSPEND if nothing was requested at all and value in G is NA.

For starters, I had a colleague introduce me to `=na()` so I'll start replacing all my text values with error values. That way, I can start making use of `=IFERROR`.

My issue is with the syntax. I'm having trouble combining multiple logical checks when TRUE or FALSE aren't explicitly being used. I've tried using IFS and OR to combine the formulas but those are all looking for explicit Boolean values, which I'm not using.

I was able to replace Col G's "N/A" with `=na()` without any issue. Filled down as expected.

Now, when I try replacing all the "N/A" entries in Col H's formula, it starts throwing errors that I have too many arguments.

I also tried changing Col I to something like `=OR(IF(G4<TODAY(),"SUSPEND","HOLD TICKET"),IF(G4="N/A","SUSPEND"))` but this is returning a #VALUE! error. I suspect because the =OR() was looking for boolean values and only finding a date or #N/A.

How can I accomplish what I'm looking for here?

Answer (score 1):

A genius colleague of mine pointed out this is much simpler than I'm making it. We elected to switch back to Text value "N/A" instead of "=NA()" for flexibility.

New Formulas.

G `=IF(T4=FALSE,"N/A",(D4+IF(T4,90)))`

H `=IF(G4="N/A","N/A",IF(G4<TODAY(),"DISABLE FORWARD","HOLD TICKET"))`

I `=IF(G4="N/A","SUSPEND",IF(G4<TODAY(),"SUSPEND","HOLD TICKET"))`

At one point we also tried adding =ISNA(ISERROR but we figured actually seeing #N/A! in a working table was a little messy.

The takeaway from this that I learned is that IFS isn't always necessary and nested IF statements are just as powerful.